# Different Module Flavours In Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

This started occurring on the Android Studio Version 2.2. My project has 2 modules in total as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Build Variant]

Also seen above I have a mock flavour for the `sdk` module. I used to be able to switch the individual module, i.e `mockDebug` for `sdk` while the rest remain unchanged.

However, this is no longer possible for the latest Android Studio. I cannot change `sdk` to `mockDebug` anymore while keeping the build variant for `app`.

Please find the `build.gradle` of my `sdk` module below:
[image: Build.gradle]

Would anyone be able to help with this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the same problem. Can you try `productFlavour` on a new project to see if there any problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for this. I had the gradle file to compile according to the different flavours of the module which my main depended upon. This is shown as below:

`releaseCompile project(path: ':sdk', configuration: 'prodRelease')
debugCompile project(path: ':sdk', configuration: 'prodDebug')
testCompile project(path: ':sdk', configuration: 'mockDebug')`

The fix is to remove the second line `debugCompile()`